# Turning output into 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I do some calculations with two 2D array with two for loop.

The answer I got are several seperate numbers.

Is there any method that I can turn the answers into one 2D array? Like this:

```
[[6.0, 10.9], [24.0, 33.8]]
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(1, 3):
    arr2d_1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
    arr2d_2 = np.array([[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]])
    for j in range(0,2):
        res = (arr2d_1*i+arr2d_2*j)/arr2d_1*i
        sum_res = np.sum(res)
        print(sum_res)
```

This is the result:

```
6.0
10.900000000000002
24.0
33.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use:

```
import numpy as np

result = []
for i in range(1, 3):
    arr2d_1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
    arr2d_2 = np.array([[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]])

    r = []
    for j in range(0,2):
        res = (arr2d_1*i+arr2d_2*j)/arr2d_1*i
        sum_res = np.sum(res)
        r.append(sum_res)
    result.append(r)

print(result) # or np.array(result)
```

output:

```
[[6.0, 10.900000000000002], [24.0, 33.8]]
```

you are storing the intermediary results from each full inner `for` loop iteration in a new list for each outer iteration

Answer (score 1):

Yep so in this particular solution you could start by building a 2d array with zeroes, and fill up each element with the relevant calculation

```
results = np.zeros([2,2])
for i in range(1, 3):
    arr2d_1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
    arr2d_2 = np.array([[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]])
    for j in range(0,2):
        res = (arr2d_1*i+arr2d_2*j)/arr2d_1*i
        sum_res = np.sum(res)
        results[i-1,j] = sum_res

results
->
array([[ 6. , 10.9],
       [24. , 33.8]])
```

But more broadly you can use np.reshape() to get arrays how you like them.

```
array = np.array([1,2,3,4)
array.reshape(2,2)
-> 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```